# Excel to CI PeopleCode Usage

Tags: peoplesoft, peoplecode

I am trying to get a better understanding how how a Excel to Component Interface definition uses Component and/or Record PeopleCode to execute business logic/validations.

If I open a Component definition (that my Component Interface (CI) uses) and click on the Structure tab I have a list of all the records and fields in the component. I can expand a record and right click on a specific field and it brings up a "Component PeopleCode" editor window. I've noticed that for a specific field on a record, the Component PeopleCode does not have any code in it, however the actual Record PeopleCode does has PeopleCode for the same field. My question is when the Excel to CI runs, does it execute the PeopleCode only associated to the Component, and/or the Record PeopleCode? Here are a couple screenshots to illustrate the above:

**Record PeopleCode for field ITM_STATUS_FUTURE (has code):**

[image]

**Component PeopleCode for same Record/field ITM_STATUS_FUTURE:**

[image]

I'd like to know whether the CI will execute both the Component and Record Peoplecode above. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The Component Interface will execute both the Record PeopleCode and the Component Record PeopleCode.  You can find more information in the PeopleCode Developer's Guide, PeopleCode and the Component Processor section.

The ordering is that it processes by record, and for each record, it processes record PeopleCode and then component PeopleCode.

Comment: Thanks. I had read PeopleBooks and it wasn't clear to me whether both Record PeopleCode and Component Record PeopleCode executed in a Component Interface.